# Two tangent unit circles and one small circle tangent to both of them

Tags: geometry, circles

You have 2 identical unit circles (radius 1) tangent to each other. On top between them a small circle is placed such that it's tangent to both the unit circles. The blue line is tangent to all three circles.

Here is an image depicting what I mean:

[image]

**Question:** What is the radius of the small circle?

---

Is there an easy way to solve this problem? I'm sure there is, but I can't seem to come up with a simple method. It looks like it's around 1/4. How would you guys approach this problem or problems of this type in general? Please, try to explain it, if possible, in simple terms.

Comment: All you need is Pythagoras theorem. First use it to get the height of the centre of small circle from the horizontal red line in terms of r. This height is nothing but $1-r$. Answer should be exactly $1/4$

Comment: @TonyPizza Oh, that was too easy :D 1^2+(1-r)^2=(1+r)^2. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use the Descartes theorem. If four circles  with radii( $r_1, r_2, r_3, r$) are  tangents , then we have:

$$(\frac1{r_1}+\frac1{r_2}+\frac1{r_3}+\frac1{r})^2=2(\frac1{r_1^2}+\frac1{r_2^2}+\frac1{r_3^2}+\frac1{r^2})$$

Here $r_1+r_2=1$ and $r_3=\infty$ which represent the line , so we have:

$$(1+1+0+\frac 1 r)^2=2(1+1+0+\frac 1{r^2})$$

which finally gives:

$4r+1=2\Rightarrow r=\frac14$

Comment: Cool never seen this theorem before. That gives me the general solution too on how to solve these type of problems.